# How to normalize data to 1 such that each value receives a weight proportional to their own value

Tags: normalization, linear-algebra

I have some data that do not sum to 1 that I would like to have sum to 1.

0.0232

0.05454

0.2154

0.5

0.005426

0.024354

0.00000456

sum: 0.82292456

I could just multiply each value by 1.0/0.82292456 and then have the sum be 1.00, but then all values would receive a factor adjustment of the same proportion (i.e 0.17707544).

I'd like to increase each value based on the size of the value itself. In other words, 0.5 would get a proportionally larger adjustment than 00000456 would.

I am not sure how to determine these adjustments that could potentially be additive, multiplicative, or both.

Any hints or suggestions would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: what's your goal here? why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have some aircraft emissions that I would like to spatially allocate using a pre-determined set of normalized factors. Currently, these factors do not add to 1, but I would like them to. I additionally want to give the larger factors more emissions, proportionally, than the smaller factors.

Comment: gotcha. it seems like you want what @james large said. multiplication will give the larger ones proportionally more than the smaller factors. if you wanted to change those ratios, however, you could always square the values and then have them sum to 1, but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could just multiply each value by 1.0/0.82292456 and then have the sum be 1.00, but then all values would receive a factor adjustment of the same proportion (i.e 0.17707544).

OK, That's what I'd do.  Why is "a factor adjustment of the same proportion" a problem?

> I'd like to increase each value based on the size of the value itself.

In that case, you should multiply each value by 1.0/0.82292456 because that's what multiplication does.